# LWC with external js lib not loading when use LWS security checkbox is checked

Tags: lightning-web-components, locker-service, lws

We have DHTMLX Gantt library loaded in a LWC and deployed to multiple orgs, and we are facing this issue where if we uncheck the "use LWC Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components and Aura components" option from Setup->Session settings, the component loads up all well, but when the checkbox is checked the component does not load and in the browser console we get an error

```
"aura_prod.js:55 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'error')
    at Object.apply (aura_prod.js:55:88749)
    at aura_prod.js:55:65046
    at tn.hybridGetTrap [as get] (eval at Ty (aura_prod.js:55:71352), <anonymous>:3:19975)
    at e (eval at <anonymous> (eval at Ty (aura_prod.js:55:71352)), <anonymous>:35:167357)
    at Object.eval [as method] (eval at <anonymous> (eval at Ty (aura_prod.js:55:71352)), <anonymous>:35:167592)
    at Object.getState (eval at <anonymous> (eval at Ty (aura_prod.js:55:71352)), <anonymous>:35:77879)
    at c._render_tasks_scales (eval at <anonymous> (eval at Ty (aura_prod.js:55:71352)), <anonymous>:11:52216)
    at c.refresh (eval at <anonymous> (eval at Ty (aura_prod.js:55:71352)), <anonymous>:11:57090)
    at c.setSize (eval at <anonymous> (eval at Ty (aura_prod.js:55:71352)), <anonymous>:11:47608)
    at e.setContentSize (eval at <anonymous> (eval at Ty (aura_prod.js:55:71352)), <anonymous>:11:255682)
a"
```

Can we keep the checkbox unchecked and let it use Lightning locker instead of LWC? What would be the implications?
Is there any way by which we can resolve this by keep the checkbox on?
I need help on the above issue. Thank you

Comment: Do you know what that checkbox does?

Comment: @NickCook - It enables Lightning web security in the org, which is the new client side security feature for Lightning components. It basically replaces Lightning locker.